# Jquery Popup Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm new to JavaScript and Jquery. I googled Jquery pop-up examples online. I want the message to say "Our website is not yet complete, but feel free to browse what we have." I'll include the code example I found, but it looks really weird. I'm not sure what the name of the function is and how to execute it using the window.onload = function(); code. I also want to have a button 'close' that closes the text box. Here'a what it should look like: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

Here's the first part:

```
    (function($){

    $.confirm = function(params){

        if($('#confirmOverlay').length){
            // A confirm is already shown on the page:
            return false;
        }

        var buttonHTML = '';
        $.each(params.buttons,function(name,obj){

            // Generating the markup for the buttons:

            buttonHTML += '<a href="#" class="button '+obj['class']+'">'+name+'<span></span></a>';

            if(!obj.action){
                obj.action = function(){};
            }
        });

        var markup = [
            '<div id="confirmOverlay">',
            '<div id="confirmBox">',
            '<h1>',params.title,'</h1>',
            '<p>',params.message,'</p>',
            '<div id="confirmButtons">',
            buttonHTML,
            '</div></div></div>'
        ].join('');

        $(markup).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn();

        var buttons = $('#confirmBox .button'),
            i = 0;

        $.each(params.buttons,function(name,obj){
            buttons.eq(i++).click(function(){

                // Calling the action attribute when a
                // click occurs, and hiding the confirm.

                obj.action();
                $.confirm.hide();
                return false;
            });
        });
    }

    $.confirm.hide = function(){
        $('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Here's the second part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.item .delete').click(function(){

        var elem = $(this).closest('.item');

        $.confirm({
            'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
            'buttons'   : {
                'Yes'   : {
                    'class' : 'blue',
                    'action': function(){
                        elem.slideUp();
                    }
                },
                'No'    : {
                    'class' : 'gray',
                    'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                }
            }
        });

    });

});

            $(markup).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn();

            var buttons = $('#confirmBox .button'),
                i = 0;

            $.each(params.buttons,function(name,obj){
                buttons.eq(i++).click(function(){

                    // Calling the action attribute when a
                    // click occurs, and hiding the confirm.

                    obj.action();
                    $.confirm.hide();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }

        $.confirm.hide = function(){
            $('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

    })(jQuery);
```

EDIT: I got the message to show up on loading. I changed the code in the second part to

> $('.item .delete').ready(function(){

Comment: do you want a pop-up or a dialog for it.

Comment: What do you mean? I want it to pop up when the page loads. I'm not sure what you mean by dialog.

Comment: pop-up in browser means that a new browser instance open with the same session information by the application. And a dialog means that a Div based Confirmation box open (just like an alert) and its a part of the same page

Comment: any way i think i got your point and saw the example too.

Comment: Dialog, then.  I want something elegant instead of the traditional JavaScript alert.

Comment: Do you think you could help me then? I need it to happen on load and I just want a close button. It's for this website I've been coding. http://www.gracepensacolacom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on the page.

Make sure that the `first part` of your question is also included.

It will make a dialog box on the page center with a message and with a close button.

Also you can change the Heading, I just added a placeholder.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.confirm({
    'title'     : 'Heading Goes Here',
    'message'   : 'Our website is not yet complete, '
                  + 'but feel free to browse what we have.',
    'buttons'   : {
        'Close'   : {
          'class' : 'blue',
          'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case.
        }
    {
  });

});
```

Comment: hanks. Could you explain the code? Also, how do I get the script to run using onload.window?

Comment: `first part` is an utility JS for dialog. By using that JS and using jQuery created a dialog box on page load. `onload` is same as `$(document).ready()` in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out just a couple minutes before you posted your last comment.

Answer (score 3):

Dialog window like, please see this image :

[image]

And please check this example: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

There is various types of pop models: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/

And coding samples: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#examples

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the code? Also, how do I get the script to run using onload.window?