# Confirmation Popup in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, confirmation

I have a piece of code that when the user clicks the save button I need to query the database and see if this new record will create a duplicate.  If it will create a duplicate I need it to pop up a confirmation box that informs the user that the new record is a potential dup, but still allow the save to continue if they select yes.  I have the dup check working but need to know how to pop the confirmation box if needed and then continue with the save if no dup is found or if the user select to save anyways.

Comment: jquery popup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466523/jquery-popup-box

Comment: @DaveA but in this case i have to call server side function then take result from there and then show confirm dialog box.

Comment: You cannot create a popup from server. only from client. I assumed you were using an Ajax call to check for dupes.

Comment: is any way around to achieve this in asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an action with JsonResult in controller which will validate your record. You can call it from Jquery and create popup with your requirement in Jquery. you can modify the following  basic example:

C# code

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
public JsonResult ValidateRecord(clsType objType)
{       
     Boolean isDuplicate = CheckDup(objType);
     return Json(new {result = isDuplicate}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

JavaScript

```
function ValidateSubmit() 
{
$.getJSON('/Your/ValidateRecord', { TypeProp1:TypeValue1 }, function(data) {
    var showPopUp=data.result;
    if(showPopUp){
    //Your popup and form submission code 
    }
});
```

}

Please mark as answer if you find it helpful